# Convert CSS in react native

Tags: html, css, react-native

How can I convert the CSS to do the following in react native implementation?

```css
.parent.parent-1 .sub-class-1 {
  background: yellow;
}

.parent.parent-2 .sub-class-1, .parent.parent-2 .sub-class-2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent parent-1">
  <div class="sub-class-1">Test1</div>
  <div class="sub-class-2">Test2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the `div` as a `View` and then create a stylesheet for styles, so -

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  subClass: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
});
```

```
<View style={styles.parent}>
   <View style={styles.subClass}><Text>Text1</Text</View>
   <View style={styles.subClass}><Text>Text2</Text</View>
</View>
```

disclaimer - I'm not so sure your CSS is correct, I don't see where you are using 'parent-2' so I've just assumed a simple example

Answer (score 0):

You can use **styled-components**:

**Example:**

```
export const Container = styled.View`
  height:10px;
  width:20px;
  flex-direction:row;
  background-color:null;
`
```

**Use:**

Wrap your view or child in Container shown below:

```
<Container>
   //...rest of your code
</Container>
```

**Reference Link:**

[styled-components with React Native](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-styled-components-with-react-native/)

[styled-components](https://styled-components.com/)